# There is no big difference between reacting after 6h and after 20h

Tags: perfect-constructions

The context: It's like there are two reactions and one has reacted for 6h while the other one has reacted for 20h. But there is no difference between them.

I want to say

> There is no big difference between reacting after 6h and after 20h.

Is this example correct?

Or if could be more accurate to say

> There is no big difference in the results between reacting after 6h and 20h

Or if there is a more accurate and natural way to form the sentence?

Comment: Maybe something like **There isn't a significant difference between a reaction that occurs 6 hours later and one that occurs 20 hours later.**

Comment: You could also say **6 hours from now** or **6 hours since the start**.

Answer (score 1):

"Reacting" (the gerund) usually refers to when a person *reacts* to some event:

> Deidre tried to ignore him, afraid **reacting** would only draw more attention to herself.

In a scientific context, it may be less confusing to instead use "reaction":

> There was no significant difference between the **reactions** at 6h and at 20h.
>
> There was no significant **reaction** after 6 hours, nor after 20 hours.

or some conjugation of the verb "react":

> After 6 hours we observed that substance A **had reacted** with substance B, but there was no difference between this and what we observed after 20 hours.